# Finding sentences contained in other sentences

Tags: c#

Given two lists of sentences, how do I find the sentence pairs, where all the words from one sentence are contained in the other?

Example:

```
List1: {"free bar", "hello world", "foo"}
List2: {"hello there world", "foobar", "bar"}
```

The output should tell me that "hello world" from List1 is contained in "hello there world" from List2, and "bar" from List2 is contained in "free bar" from List1. "foo" and "foobar" on the other hand are not a match.

I have tried running through everything and matching with an regular expression, using c# and LINQ, but this is too slow. Often the lists consist of at least 2500 sentences that are 1-6 words long.

Just as a note, it dosen't have to be lists. Could be HashMaps or anything else. Hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an approach using a dictionary of hashsets for preprocessing `list2` - this overall is O(n*m), n = number of words in list 1, m= number of sentences in list 2 (excluding the preprocessing):

```
var list1 = new List<string>() { "free bar", "hello world", "foo" };
var list2 = new List<string>() { "hello there world", "foobar", "bar" };
var wordMap = new Dictionary<string, HashSet<int>>();

for(int i = 0; i< list2.Count; i++)
{
    var words = list2[i].Split(' ');
    foreach(var word in words)
    {
        if(!wordMap.ContainsKey(word))
        {
            wordMap[word] = new HashSet<int>();
        }
        wordMap[word].Add(i);
    }
}

foreach(var item in list1)
{
    bool foundMatch = false;
    var words = item.Split(' ');
    for (int i = 0; i < list2.Count;i++ )
    {
        foundMatch = words.All(word => !wordMap.ContainsKey(word) ? false : wordMap[word].Contains(i));
        if(foundMatch)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Found matching sentence in list 2: " + list2[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

In reality this should be much faster than any string comparisons.